# Select block text (line vty 0 4) using powershell/regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I need a script that can pull the `line vty 0 4` section from a cisco config text file. can anyone one recommend a method using powershell/regex?

**ex:** I need the following block test pulled and output to a file, or just a screen output.

```
line con 0
 exec-timeout 10 0
 timeout login response 30
 privilege level 1
  special-character-bits 7
 exec
line vty 0 4  >STARING AT THIS LINE
 access-class VTY-ACL in
 motd-banner
 exec-banner
 exec-timeout 10 0
 timeout login response 30
 privilege level 1
 logging synchronous >ENDING AT THIS LINE
line vty 5 15
 access-class VTY-ACL in
 motd-banner
 exec-banner
 exec-timeout 10 0
 timeout login response 30
 privilege level 1
 logging synchronous
```

Comment: This can certainly be done in powershell. You should start with the `Get-Content` cmdlet and search the web for one of the multitude of examples of people doing this. Then write some code and ask back here when you have specific issues with the code that you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is named "file.text" in the current path:

```
Get-Content .\file.text -Raw |Select-String '(?ms)^line vty 0 4.*(?=^\w)' |Foreach {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Or using aliases to golfcode it:

```
cat .\file.text -Raw|sls '(?ms)^line vty 0 4.*(?=^\w)'|%{$_.Matches.Value}
```

The `(?ms)` in the pattern sets the `m` and `s` modifiers

> **m modifier:**  **m**ulti line.
>   Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
>   **s modifier:**  **s**ingle line.
>   Dot
>   matches newline characters

So the `.*` will match anything till the [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=^\w)` detects a new line followed by a word-character ahead.

Note that the `-Allmatches` switch for the Select-String was omitted since it's expected that such file would only contain one `line vty 0 4` section.

Comment: Works fine +1, you can omit -Allmatches (as it refers to all matches on one line), also the ForEach could be condensed to one : `|Foreach {$_.Matches.Value}` A hint on the [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the RegEx could be helpful.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks for the hints!  I'll play around with that for a while and golf-code it a bit.